# Getting error while running terraform code on jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, terraform

What will be the solution for this error?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/augS3.png)

I have added the the stage as:

```
stage('Terraform Plan') {
            steps {
                echo 'Terraform Initilization is in Progress!'
                sh 'terraform plan -var-file=terraform.tfvars -out=tfplan.txt'
            }
        }
```

Comment: pleaee paste the output into a code block instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply states that "terraform.tfvars" is missing. First ensure that the file actually exists in the directory before you run the terraform command. You can do this by running commands such as `pwd` to see where you are and `ls` to see all the files present in the directory you are running the Terraform command from. Then adjust your command so that the correct tfvars file is specified.